# Does /* has another use case in javascript?

Tags: javascript

[I was reading a tutorial](http://artoale.com/tutorial/brackets/2013/09/30/writing-brackets-extension-01/), and found that the lines

```
/*jslint vars: true, plusplus: true, devel: true, nomen: true, regexp: true, indent: 4, maxerr: 50 */
/*global define, $, brackets, window, Mustache */
```

So my problem is, what i learn is that `/* */` is used as multiline comments, so why this is used as global definition?

NB: Google deletes my // or /* from search, i dont know why it dont escape them!

Comment: It isn't global definition. It's just letting `jshint` know that you have already globally defined those variables. When it examines your code and sees you using variables that don't exist, it will yell at you. So this is just your way to let it know that those variables do in fact exist.

Comment: ah, now it makes it more clear for me, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jshint error "From within your code, you've access to some global variables:" indicated that you are using global variables in your code (your actual code, not the flags in comments you have posted).

The line "/*global define, $, brackets, window, Mustache */" is telling jshint to define variables called $, brackets, window and Mustache. This will prevent jshint from generating errors based on these global variables. If your still getting the error then you must be using other global variables.

You are probably missing a var statement somewhere. Post your whole code if you still need help.

Comment: it was a tutorial (the link is in the question) and as a beginner, that was weird for me to see the multiline serving as crutial part of code! i thought it was something related to node.js :D

Answer (score 3):

some external libraries/frameworks (jslint in this case) read comments.

Basically the comments are notes to jslint, turning on flags and telling it what variables are global.

Comment: it was weird from me, since it said: `From within your code, you've access to some global variables:` and as beginner, this is not what i know!
 but.... jslint is for the code quality only? isent that?
edit: as @squint explained it, this is to not make errors when it dont find variables...now it makes sense